# How to expose two HTTPS ports?

Tags: traefik

I am considering switching to `traefik` to control my docker containers and everything looks great so far. One thing I could not find in the docs is how to expose several HTTPS ports.

The documentation mentions that the exposed port is defined as:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
```

**What should I put there to tell `traefik` that I would like to listen for HTTPS traffic on `443` and `50443`?**

Answer (score 0):

Just define another entrypoint following the same scheme but name it differently e.g. `[entrypoints.verysecure]`. Remember that every TLS entrypoint needs a cert/key configuration

Comment: Thank you. I thought that `entryPoint.https` was a reserved name (the `https` part)